# show ebay feedback on my website

Tags: php

Well, I have web host and I would like to get the code that shows my ebay feedback, but what I need is not a code that related for another website, what I mean is that I want to get my own code.
I found very good code that can help me but still I need your help, here's the code and it works well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://gamila-secret.comyr.com/Styles/feedback.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pc-homecare.co.uk/ebay/feedback.php?id=[USERID]&site=[SITEID]&seller=[SELLER]"></script>
```

As I said I need my own code, what I did is getting the style file and rebuild it, but still I need to get the javascript file, I just went to that page "`http://www.pc-homecare.co.uk/ebay/feedback.php?id=[USERID]&site=[SITEID]&seller=[SELLER]`" which I got from the code, and I copied its source(its codes), then I made a new file in my server with that code but unfortunately it did not worked.
Any ideas about how can I get the functions from the codes up to work on my own server?

Comment: As it is a PHP file the code is running on the server side, not client side. You won't be able to get the PHP code if that's what you're after - only what it spits out (in this case some Javascript for writing the HTML output).

Comment: Your question is too vague, try rewording it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_file_contents` in PHP like so to get the contents of a URL (see php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');

?>
```

Or,

```
<?php

$section = file_get_contents('http://example.com', NULL, NULL, 20, 14);
var_dump($section);

?>
```

, to get a section of it. But of course you can always parse the contents of the URL from the first example using PHP regex (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Echoing HTML is a simple matter in PHP (see php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

```
<?php

$src = 'http://example.com/script.js':
echo '<script src="' . $src . '"></script>';

?>
```

, using concatenation (see php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

I hope that helps.

Comment: I really don't understand how could I apply that as I want to use it. Also I don't know how to code php. But anyway I will up vote for your effort, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a hack, but it would definitely work..

Try installing PhantomJS (or any server-side javascript engine) and using it to load any page that displays your ebay feedback score, then grab the element containing your feedback score with jQuery and return it to a file and read that file with PHP. Might be a little slow (a few seconds, maybe), but it'll get the job done.